# Causation vs correlation problem in case of fixing other parameters and changing only one

Tags: statistics

I have a game that players play. D7 retention is defined as percentage of players who installed my game and after exactly 7 days later they played my game.

Now I am doing analytics and it shows that only 10% of players play my game on day 7. I change the difficulty of the game significantly and collect analytical data. Data shows that now D7 is 15%.

Can I conclude that D7 change is caused by difficulty change or this is one of the examples that correlation is not causation? And how I can identify if I can think of causation or not.

Physicists, psychologists in experiments have done a lot such things. Fixing all parameters changing one and observing the behavior change and drawing conclusion. What is the right way to approach this?

Comment: Comparing the new D1 with the old D7 is changing more than one parameter. Did you mean to say D7 both times?

Comment: Yes, sorry typo. Both should be D7.

Comment: It seems to me that a good scientific test would be to randomly select half the users one week and give them the old version of the game to install, while the other half install the new version. That way you control for the possibility that between the first measurement and the second, game players got smarter, or less smart, or less patient, or that you launched the new version during midterms, or whatever else would affect D7. But it also seems to me that the data you have should be worth something, especially if you're willing to take a chance that nothing changed with time.